# Custom UiObject2Condition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-uiautomator

Is it possible to extend public abstract class [UiObject2Condition](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiObject2Condition)?

Doing in this way

```
class NoChildCondition: UiObject2Condition<Boolean>() {
    override fun apply(obj: UiObject2?): Boolean {
        return obj?.childCount == 0
    }
}
```

causes an error: `public open fun apply(obj: UiObject2?): Boolean defined in circlecomplete.ciom.uitests.NoChildCondition' has no access to 'public/*package*/ abstract fun apply(p0: UiObject2!): Boolean! defined in androidx.test.uiautomator.UiObject2Condition', so it cannot override it`.

Note that `UiObject2Condition` is an empty subclass of `androidx.test.uiautomator.Condition<UiObject2, R>` and `Condition` is not public.

Implementing `apply` method causes a compilation error. Not implementing it compiles but causes a runtime error.

UIAutomator version: 2.2.0

UiObject2Condition decompilation:

```
package androidx.test.uiautomator;

public abstract class UiObject2Condition<R> extends Condition<UiObject2, R> {
    public UiObject2Condition() {
    }
}
```

Condition decompilation:

```
package androidx.test.uiautomator;

abstract class Condition<T, R> {
    Condition() {
    }

    abstract R apply(T var1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `androidx.test.uiautomator` package and adding class into it works fine.

```
package androidx.test.uiautomator

class NoChildCondition: UiObject2Condition<Boolean>() {
    override fun apply(obj: UiObject2?): Boolean {
        return obj?.childCount == 0
    }
}
```